# Navigating between screens pressing headers image

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator, react-android

Simple question: I am trying to navigate from `HomeScreen.js` to `MessageScreen` once pressing the `HomeScreen.js` header's image.

However, when I press the image an error pops up:

```
TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function (In 'navigation-navigate("MessageScreen")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)
```

What is the problem with the navigation?
This is the main code from `App.js`

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
      HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: (navigation) => ({
            headerShown: true,
            title:'As minhas viagens',
            headerTintColor:'black',
            headerRight: ()=>  
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")}>
                    <Image 
                    source={require("./assets/message.png")} 
                    style={{width: 40,height: 40, borderRadius: 40 / 2}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        })
      },
      MessageScreen: {
        screen: MessageScreen,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          headerShown: true
        })
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
      HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
          return {
            headerShown: true,
            title:'As minhas viagens',
            headerTintColor:'black',
            headerRight: () =>  
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")}>
                    <Image 
                    source={require("./assets/message.png")} 
                    style={{width: 40,height: 40, borderRadius: 40 / 2}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        })
      },
      MessageScreen: {
        screen: MessageScreen,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          headerShown: true
        })
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I would really like to now though, why do I need to code "return" as a children of navigation options?

Comment: The braces after `() => {}` are read as a function block and not as an object block. So, the compiler thinks you just wrote down some properties inside a block instead of returning an actual object.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud pass props to your function otherwise it has no way of knowing what this 'navigation' is , try something like

```
headerRight: ({navigation})=>  
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")}>
                        <Image 
                        source={require("./assets/message.png")} 
                        style={{width: 40,height: 40, borderRadius: 40 / 2}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

or this?

```
headerRight: (props)=>  
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")}>
                        <Image 
                        source={require("./assets/message.png")} 
                        style={{width: 40,height: 40, borderRadius: 40 / 2}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I have tried both methods but I get 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: sorry then. Well you could try using useNavigation hook. But it doesnt look like you are using RN navigation 5

Comment: I am using RN 4.3. I am kind of new to react native, so why should I use RN 5 instead?

Comment: 5 is new version of react navigation. It is much simpler to use and adds a ton of features which would definitely help you. for example this 'useNavigation' hook which you can just pass into any React component and just use navigation without any props passing. BUT rewriting whole navigation just to solve this problem is probaly overkill.

Comment: Well ye, it was what I was thinking now. I would have to start almost everything over with my app just to solve this little issue :\, It's just not worth it at the moment.

Comment: Its not like you have to ovverwite all of your app. My company, we did the same thing, and we had quite large codebase allready. You dont have to delete your react components or anything. it took me ~2 days to rewrite our app and push new release. It was definitely worth it in long run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")
```

or

`props.navigation.navigate("MessageScreen")` ?

Comment: Yes I did, and I get 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')